# Best practice to achieve max performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

What is more efficient(faster): to store the same tweet twice in `Tweet` table, once for `user1` and again for `user2` or using join between `Tweet` and `Friend` to get the results ?

```
Tweet => Id
         UserId
         SenderId
         JSONdata

User =>  Id

Friend => UserId 
          FriendId
```

with join :

```
SELECT TOP 20 a.* FROM Tweet a INNER JOIN Friend b ON a.SenderId = b.UserId WHERE b.UserId = {0}
```

or I can save the tweet twice for the sender and the receiver and use a simple query :

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM TWEET WHERE UserId = {0}
```

which one is more faster, if joins then what type of index should I use, I'll be happy to hear any advice.

thanx

Comment: Have a peek at [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), it may be better suited for your question (not sure though).

Comment: Efficient ***how!?!?*** In terms of disk usage? -> store it once and link it. In terms of query speed? That's up for grabs... storing it twice might be faster to query - but you'll get into a plethora of other issues (like consistency and maintenance) - is that worth it?

Comment: The title says "max performance", the body says "more efficient".  Either way, you would need to specify a lot more information: cost of storage, the various queries to be performed and their relative frequencies, coefficient of friendliness of your average tweet, ... .

Comment: @marc_s : Can you explain these 'other issues' ?

Comment: The other commenters are correct, I'd advice you to go with a normalized database until you experience performance issues, that would be the time to start optimizing further. IF you really want a definite answer to your question now, the easiest would be to test it.

Comment: @Rawhi: things like: if you need to change some value in your data, and you have stored that data in a gazillion different places - how can you ensure data consistency? What do you do when your data suddenly is *inconsistent*? Do you have methods/policies to fix that - or do you just not care about that?

Answer (score 0):

Store your data only once (Tweet) and you will not have any consistency issues.  Unless you are developing this as a heavy OLAP system (i.e. data warehouse), then you should be normalizing.